# Receiving Duplicate Messages from WebSocket Server in React Component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, websocket, frontend

## Problem Description:

I'm currently working on a project where I'm using a WebSocket server to send real-time updates to a React component. However, I'm encountering a problem where the same message is being displayed multiple times in the component, and I'm not sure what's causing this behavior. Here's a breakdown of my setup:

In my React component, I've implemented a WebSocket connection using the useEffect hook. I'm listening for "message" events from the WebSocket server and updating the component's state with the received data. However, I've noticed that messages are sometimes displayed multiple times, even though the server is sending them only once.

## Relevant Code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const Booking = () => {
  const [receivedData, setReceivedData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const socket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:3000");

    socket.addEventListener("open", () => {
      console.log("Connected to WebSocket server");
    });

    socket.addEventListener("message", (event) => {
      console.log("Received message from server:", event.data);

      try {
        const parsedData = JSON.parse(event.data);
        console.log(parsedData);

        // Append the received JSON to the existing data array
        setReceivedData((prevData) => [...prevData, parsedData]);
      } catch (error) {
        console.log("Received non-JSON data:", event.data);
      }
    });

    socket.addEventListener("close", () => {
      console.log("WebSocket connection closed");
    });

    return () => {
      socket.close(); // Close the WebSocket connection when component unmounts
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Received Data:</h2>
      <ul>
        {receivedData.map((data, index) => (
          <li key={index}>{JSON.stringify(data)}</li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Booking;
```

## Expected Behavior:

I expect each message sent from the WebSocket server to be displayed once in the component's UI. However, I'm seeing the same message displayed multiple times.

## Troubleshooting Steps Taken:

1. I verified that the WebSocket server is sending each message only once.
2. I confirmed that the React component is not re-rendering unexpectedly.
3. I checked for issues with the WebSocket connection, but it seems stab

## Question:

What could be causing the received messages to be displayed multiple times in the React component? Is there something wrong with my implementation? Are there any common pitfalls that I might be overlooking?

I appreciate any insights or suggestions to help me resolve this issue.

Comment: Do you by any chance use `<StrictMode>`?

Comment: If you are, its almost certainly this: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/10387. The websocket API doesn't allow `close()` to be called when its still connecting and `StrictMode` makes effects run twice in dev. This doesn't matter normally if you have cleanup functions, which you do. However, cleaning up websockets has that caveat on close which makes this uniquely awkward.